# Cant log into newly registered AAD application. Error code: AADSTS650051: Says my organization is in an umanaged state

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal, azure-ad-msal

So I have registered a new multi-tenant AAD application but trying to log in using the same account I created it with gives me the error

```
MSAL.Desktop.4.5.0.0.MsalServiceException: 
    ErrorCode: invalid_client
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: 
AADSTS650051: "Using application 'TestApplication' is currently not supported for your organization sample-company.ch  because it is in an unmanaged state. An administrator needs to claim ownership of the company by DNS validation of sample-company.ch before the application TestApplication can be provisioned."
```

The domain name in question is already verified, so im not sure whats wrong here. After registering the app I just followed their Windows Desktop App Quickstart Guide and tried logging in with their sample project 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-desktop-msgraph-v2/

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

Since your application is for multi-tenant, you probably didn't do user or admin consent for the target tenant.

Try to add `&prompt=admin_consent` in your request to force admin consent. Log in with an admin account to do admin consent.

Please see details from [Understand user and admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#understand-user-and-admin-consent).